# MFMailComposeViewController broke CSS styles in html template

Tags: iphone, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I use MFMailComposeViewController to send a message in **html** format. **If** my html template contains the **css styles**:

```
<div class="margin:10 10 10 0"> <a href="domain.name">Go To</a></div>
```

In this case it **works good**.

**But** if I send:

```
<a href="domain.name">Go&nbsp;To</a>
```

then I see the letter that comes with **broken styles** as there (**3D** is not my misprint)

```
<div style=3D"margin:10 10 10 10;"><a href=3D"www.google.com">Go=C2=A0To</a></div>
```

Well as the letter goes broken when I insert in the template symbols from national alphabets.

Somebody can tell what the problem and check with yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I revised my answer to add a second part of the solution:

I found two issues using MFMailComposeViewController to send HTML email with  tags.

1) For any HTML body that ends up being encoded as quoted-printable, you must put line breaks such that no lines are > 76 chars.

2) The text within the  tag should be wrapped within a  to ensure that MFMailComposeViewController does not interpret the content as a link within a link.

For example, the following HTML:

```
<a href='http://link/to/my/site.com'>site.com</a>
```

was being turned into:

```
<a href='http://link/to/my/site.com'><a href='http://site.com'>site.com</a></a>
```

By changing my HTML body to:

```
<a href='http://link/to/my/site.com'><span>site.com</span></a>
```

the email was sent correctly.

A full example:

```
NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString string];
// add HTML before the link here with line breaks (\n)
[body appendString:@"<h1>Hello User!</h1>\n"];
[body appendString:@"<a href=\"http://www.mysite.com/path/to/link\"><span>Click Me!</span></a>\n"];
[body appendString:@"<div>Thanks much!</div>\n"];
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I'll check your solution today and accept your answer.

Comment: The next sample: <h1>Super&nbsp;Test</h1> received as --000325554546db27150494e569bb
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><body bgcolor=3D"#FFFFFF"><div><h1>Super=C2=A0Test</h1></div><div></d=
iv><div><br><br>Sent from my iPhone</div></body></html>

--000325554546db27150494e569bb--

Comment: Your sample work well and for me, but if I insert non-breakable space (&nbsp;) between 'Hello' and 'User!' than your sample starts to work as I described above.

Comment: I've tested an html body with &nbsp; inside and it does cause MFMailComposeViewController to use the quoted-printable encoding. The link still functions correctly though. What is the problem this is causing for you?

Comment: You're right, it does not affect the functionality of the letter. I just want to understand what leads to use quoted-printable encoding. The line in my sample above not exceed 76 chars and contained chars only from 33-126 range. Many thanks for your participation.